# How to test the message of an expected exception in a Clojure test?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

I have following Clojure code:

```
(defn is-valid-lang
  [lang]
  (.contains (list "ru" "en" "de") lang))

(defn s
  [txt]
  {
   :desc txt
   :lang "ru"
   })

(defn s
  [txt lang]
  (if-not (is-valid-lang lang)
    (throw (.IllegalArgumentException (format "'%s' is an invalid language." lang)))
    {
     :desc txt
     :lang lang
     }
    )
  )
```

I want to write a test that verifies the message of the exception that `s` throws, if `lang` is not valid.

I wrote this:

```
(deftest s-lang-invalid-lang-test
  (is
    (thrown-with-msg?
      IllegalArgumentException
      #"'invalid-language' is an invalid language."
      (s "something" "invalid-language")
      )
    )
  )
```

The test fails due to the following error:

```
error {
 :cause "No matching field found: IllegalArgumentException for class java.lang.String"
 :via
 [{:type java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
   :message "No matching field found: IllegalArgumentException for class java.lang.String"
   :at [clojure.lang.Reflector getInstanceField "Reflector.java" 397]}]
 :trace
```

**How can I fix this and make sure that the test succeeds if `s` throws an exception with the correct message?**

**Update 1:** Fixed the multiple arity issue pointed out by cfrick.

```
(defn s
  ([txt]
   {
    :desc txt
    :lang "ru"
    })
  ([txt lang]
   (if-not (is-valid-lang lang)
     (throw (IllegalArgumentException. (format "'%s' is an invalid language." lang)))
     {
      :desc txt
      :lang lang
      })
   )
  )
```

Comment: As a sidenote, yet most likely not relevant for the question: this is
not how multi-arity functions work (`s`)

Comment: @cfrick Can you please elaborate on this point? Maybe post here a URL to a page where this is discussed in more detail.

Comment: Your second `s` overrides the first `s` - see https://clojure.org/guides/learn/functions#_multi_arity_functions how to properly define the functions for the fallback arg.

Comment: @cfrick Thanks for your feedback. Please look at the code in update 1 and tell me whether or not the definition of `s` is correct now.

Comment: De-dupe your 1-arity by calling your 2-arity `(s txt "ru")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not correctly instantiating the IllegalArgumentException. Clojure uses:

```
(IllegalArgumentException. "your message")
```

to call Java constructors. See [this article on Java interop](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#_alternative_macro_syntax)

Answer (score -1):

As an alternate technique, you can use a regex search of the Exception error message as demonstrated below:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn thrower
  [lang]
  (throw (ex-info "invalid language" {:lang lang})))

(dotest
  (throws? (thrower "bogosity")) ; just verify it throws an exception, ignoring type and message
    ; `(throws? ...)` is a convenience fn from tupelo.test (also `dotest`)

  (try
    (thrower "bogosity")
    (catch Exception e
      (let [s (str e)]
        (is (re-find #"invalid language" s)) ; returns "invalid language"
        (is (re-find #"bogosity" s)))        ; returns "bogosity"
      )))
```

In a unit test, it is often easier to search for an  expected string fragment (such as in in the Exception error message) than it is to do a string equality comparison.  The full Exception string is:

```
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: invalid language {:lang "bogosity"}
```

We use the [tupelo.test library](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/21.01.26b/api/tupelo.test) for convenience. The function `is-nonblank=` is also handy.

From [tupelo.string](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/21.01.26b/api/tupelo.string), we also have these helper functions:

- lowercase=
- nonblank-lines=
- nonblank=
- contains-match?
- contains-str?
- quotes->single
- quotes->double

and many others that make writing string-based tests much easier.